Why does more lift make a stronger shock?
Why does more lift make an aircraft shock stronger? In this answer, it says more lift will make a stronger shock.

The aircraft's lift contributes to the strength of the boom.

What part of making higher lift will cause a stronger shock?
I tried looking through Aerodynamics for Naval Aviators, but I couldn’t seem to find anything on this, unless I missed something.
Also looked through Introduction to Flight by John Anderson, but found nothing (again unless I wasn’t looking in the right place).

Think about lift from a thin flat plate at supersonic speed.  There are some great notes here.

This is the minimum situation to describe supersonic lift.  From far away, supersonic lift looks like this.
The main shock that will influence the boom is the one in the front from the lower surface.  Clearly, at zero angle of attack, there is not shock -- but there is no lift.
As the angle of attack is increased, so is the required turning angle, and therefore the strength of the shock is increased -- which leads to a louder boom.
You can 'add' the effects of thickness on top of this, but it really mostly adds complication.

I see, that makes sense. Thanks!
